Am I using the right method to model my zero-inflated data?
I have a dataset of workplace permits, sample size n=3000. The data is collected between 2012-2020, so if a permit was active some time between 2012-2020, I included it in my analyses. My exposure of interest is the sector (e.g,, for-profit, public, academic) and my outcome is workplace incidents. I want to test if there is an association between sector and workplace incidents. I treated workplace incidents as counts, so the outcome for each permit is the number of incidents during the time it was active. Because of the limited observed variables in my data, I was only able to include a few covariates like the timespan a permit was active, the risk level of the permit.
There are a few things I am concerned about:

Excess of zeroes (the majority of permits did not have a workplace
incident)
Non independence of workplaces (since an institution can hold
multiple permits, corresponding to multiple workplaces)
I want to stratify by time periods by aggregating years (e.g., period 1: 2012-2014, period 2: 2015-2017, etc.)
I have outliers (e.g., the range of my outcome is 0 to 30) that I think may affect my model, but I hesitate to remove them.

To address the excess of zeroes, I compared zero-inflated Poisson and zero-inflated negative binomial regression (based on AIC and BIC) to select the best fitting model. But stratification was not done during model comparison. I stratified data after selecting the best model.
I don't know how to deal with the non independence. I don't want to cluster by institution or treat it as a random effect because my exposure of interest is defined based on the institution, so there is no variation in sector between permits within the same institution. I was thinking about clustered standard errors to deal with this.
I don't know if what I've done so far is right. Is my methodology correct or completely not appropriate for my data? Please let me know if there are better ways to handle this, thank you!

Note that distributions such as Poisson can have a large number of zeros when the rate parameter is low. If you need a zero-inflated model that's fine, but I cannot tell from your description what will fit better.
